# How to use scale_fill_manual to manually define bar plot colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scale-color-manual

I am finalizing the representation of my dataset using ggplot2 and for the sake of clarity I would need a coloring scheme that defies standard ggplot2 "logic".
Below is a fake dataset to show you my needs in essence:

```html
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                  dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                  len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))
head(df2)

supp dose  len
1   VC D0.5  6.8
2   VC   D1 15.0
3   VC   D2 33.0
4   OJ D0.5  4.2
5   OJ   D1 10.0
6   OJ   D2 29.5
```

Here is the basic representation I'm using giving the plot below:

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image: Initial Plot]

What I would need is to apply a presonalized color palette (`myPalette <- c("#05eb92", "#119da4", "#ffc857")`) only to the `VC` series, while coloring `OC` series Black. Below is the expected plot I need. I am aware that this coloring scheme defies ggplot2 "logic" but I was wondering whether there is an easy way to apply it to my needs. Thanks.
[image: ExpectedPlot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a `dummy` variable in your input `df2` for the `ggplot` `fill` aesthetic. Here, "-999" refers to "OJ" and will be coloured in black.

I've also updated your `myPalette` to include black in it, and also `setNames` to it so that only "-999" will have a corresponding "black" value.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                  dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                  len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))

myPalette <- c("#05eb92", "#119da4", "#ffc857")

myPalette_with_black <- setNames(c(myPalette, "black"), 
                                 c(as.character(seq_along(myPalette)), "-999"))

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(supp) %>% 
  mutate(dummy = ifelse(supp == "VC", as.character(row_number()), "-999"))

ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill = dummy)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = myPalette_with_black) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: For the example I provided here everything works fine using your strategy! I struggle to figure out why in my real data set ggplot2 returns `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'dummy' not found`. The dataframe was correctly modified with the addition of the `dummy` column variable and the respective values, but somehow ggplot2 does not recognize it. Any suggestion why this could be the case?

Comment: There's three possibility: 1. You didn't replace your original dataframe with the output of `mutate`. 2. The input dataframe for `ggplot` wasn't the one that has the `mutate` operation performed. 3. You mis-spelled the word `dummy` somewhere in your codes. If all these suggestions don't work, I'll recommend you to put a minimal reproducible example here :)

Comment: I solved it. The issue was that in my ggplot2 script I also had a `geom_point` from a second dataframe in which the `dummy` variable was not defined yet. By dissecting the code I figured it out. Thanks!